Issue with calculating $E[X]$ for 'Siblings' problem
I am tackling a problem in the notes and have argued with a fellow student. The problem is a probability question: assume there is a table with $2n$ seats, and there are $n$ pairs of siblings which are going to sit at this table. Assuming each pair of siblings $\{b_i,g_i\}$ for $i \in \{1,2,...n\}$ has one male and one female, and males are sat between two females and vice versa, find the expectation and variance of the number of siblings sitting next to each other.
The question states that using indicator variables is very useful, and I can see that events $A_i = \{$siblings $\{b_i,g_i\}$ are next to each other$\}$ can work.
If $N$ is a random variable which is the sum of the number of siblings next to each other, so $N = \sum_{i=1}^{n}I[A_i]$, then we can find the expectation of $N$ easily: the expectation of a sum of random variables is the sum of their expectations, so $E[N] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}E[I[A_i]] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i) \hspace{2mm}(Equ. 1)$.
I am concerned about the 'values' of these probabilities. I am quite certain that I can set $P(A_i)$ as $\frac{2}{n}$, because the event $A_i$ is being asked about regardless of what is going on with other pairs. I get $\frac{2}{n}$ because a male could sit anywhere, and then the sister has two places out of $n$ that she could sit which would place her next to the brother.
So the expectation is a sum of $n$ terms, each $\frac{2}{n}$, giving 2. This is pretty interesting if it's true, as it shows having more people does not increase the expected number of pairs if people sit randomly, although the variance might change.
Issue: I was told by someone else (and saw it on this website) that we could try setting the indicator variable to be 'indicator that brother $i$ has sister $i$ on left', to avoid double counting. I'm not quite sure that this works because the situation is different: particularly we find $P(A_i)$ in $(Equ. 1)$ using $\frac{2}{n}$. On this site it shows that $E[N] = \frac{n}{n-1}$, which is different from 2. In particular they are the same for $n = 2$ at $2$ (so with four people every brother is next to their sister), but not for $n = 3$ (in my case the expectation is 2, which I evaluated as $\frac{1}{6} 0 + \frac{3}{6}2 + \frac{2}{6}3 = 2$, but in his case is $\frac{3}{2}$, which according to the enumeration is wrong here).
So I have an example that his working is wrong. I have two questions: does my working look right, and therefore the answer should be $E[N] = 2$ for all $n$. And secondly, is there a correct way to choose your events such that 'only looking to the right' gives the correct answer? (There could be, although it seems an unnecessary complication, but perhaps there is some symmetry that can be exploited to do with permutations?)

To clarify my second question in the last paragraph, the number of permutations on $n$ is even at $n!$ and we can 'flip' a sequence of $n$ people by reversing the order. I think this splits the set of permutations into two equal sized groups of size $n!/2$. I am unsure if this thinking would let me 'correct' the other student's idea.

I have just had a thought that might clarify: We are looking at two pemutations $p_1$ and $p_2$ of size $n$, and $N$ is the sum of times that $p_1(i)$ equals $p_2(i)$ or $p_2((i-1) (mod(n))$. Only one of those equalities can hold at once. So effectively we are checking if any two terms in the two permutations match at locations, or if there is a match one place back. I can see this situation does not map well onto the situation of 'only checking left' because the complexity of the problem is lost. Any advancement?
